# Windows Gallery Tag in Explorer

Tags: software

I have a series of images that I've uploaded to Windows Live Gallery (because I want to make use of the Caption) and the tags/keywords have copied across but once I start to update a tag in Explorer or Gallery it doesn't copy the content back to the other.  Does anyone know if I'm asking the impossible.

If it makes any difference the machine I'm working on could be XP, Vista or 7 depending on when and where I'm doing the update.
Ta

Comment: Just to clarify, you have 2 copies of a photo, one stored locally and another online, and you want tag updates to essentially synchronise between them? If that's the case, I don't think it's possible, but I may well be proved wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key word is "Uploaded". It means that you did make a copy of your original file. So changing metadata of one copy doesn't reflect in another copy.

Please locate the file in Windows Live Gallery, right click on it, navigate to the "Properties" menu, then check whether Location of this file is the same as your original file?

You can use alternative photo managers that allows you to change image annotations without making duplicates (uploading) of your images.

Comment: Sorry ElendilTheTail I should have said Explorer being My Computer.  Many thanks Murat, the Properties does indeed show me where they picture was "uploaded" to and if I edit that version of the picture (instead of the memory stick I had the archive on) it does indeed update the tag in one and it's visible in the other.

Comment: Additional update anyone looking for the same result.  In Windows Gallery > Options > Import tab you are able to define the exact location you want to manage the archive which makes life simpler than using teh generic Pictures folder.